# Removing Footer from First Page

Tags: header-footer

I'm using the following commands to produce a header and footer on all of the pages of my homework assignment:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Math 185 Spring 2014}
\chead{Problem Set 3}
\rhead{Jacob Kent}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.25pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.25pt}
```

How would I remove the header/footer from just the first page of my document? I want it to be on all of the other pages, just not the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Add this somewhere near the beginning of your document. I usually put it around `\maketitle` or so if that's applicable.

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```